# Remove Linux GRUB and keep Windows boot loader

Tags: windows, linux, boot, grub

My operating system was Windows 7, and recently, I installed Zorin OS (linux based on Ubuntu). At first, when I turned on my laptop Windows started automatically. I used a program to make the Windows boot loader come on and ask me what to start.

If I chose Linux, then the Linux GRUB comes on and asks me what to do. I want to remove the GRUB. I want to keep my Windows boot loader.

Comment: Isn't this question off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Have you considered what you are going to use _instead of_ GRUB to bootstrap Linux?  You have to have something if you want to actually continue using Linux, even if that something is simply a boot loader that runs directly as a boot application from Microsoft's Boot Manager.

Comment: @JdeBP ... I want to remove linux grub but keep the one from windows. i will try what hovanessyan said. Wish me good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

This [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Uninstalling_GRUB_2) should give you a step-by-step process for uninstalling GRUB.

If you want to completely remove Grub, you will have to use `bootrec.exe /FixMbr` from a Windows7 Rescue CD. [Here's how to do it](http://tonsoftech.com/tech/software/remove-grub-bootloader-from-windows-7-installation/).

Comment: This is about removing grub2 and installing grub. I think Paul wants to remove grub altogether.

Comment: `bootrec /fixmbr` would only be effective if GRUB were the MBR bootstrap program, which it clearly is not in this instance.  (It's in a VBR.)  Ironically, the second set of instructions that you point to end up _putting GRUB1 into_ the MBR, exactly the reverse of what the questioner wants.  The questioner will end up with Microsoft's Boot Manager displaced by GRUB1.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Windows 7 installation DVD or USB stick and choose the "Repair your computer" option. It should automatically remove grub from the MBR and make the system bootable (into Windows) again.